# Django. Положить файлы в корень сайта

Tags: django

Как залить какие либо файлы в корень сайта на Django?

т.е. к примеру мне нужно сейчас в корне лежал верификационный html файл от ютуба, затем потребуется robots.txt и карта сайта.

Допустим это все текстовые файлы и я смогу это сделать с помощью вьюхи и настройки урла в urls.py. Но както хочется чтобы это были просто статичные файлы.

Кроме того, а что делать если понадобится чтобы в корне находился архив, картинка, или другой любой файл?

Сейчас у меня в настройках:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
вот это-бы оставить без изменения..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кладешь `robots.txt` в `/static/` и в настройках вебсервера задаешь редирект с `/robots.txt` на `/static/robots.txt`

Ответы на тему с английской stackoverflow: [Where to put static files that should be served directly under the server root?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6574670/2787185) и [Django serving robots.txt efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424412/2787185)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
но мне чтото тоже не нравится решение с редактированием настроек вебсервера.. и сервак не мой, и прописывать надо будет там постоянно чтото..     

в приведенной вами ссылке(1) нашел решение через urls.py настроить редирект на нужный файл.   

я сделал так:   
создал папку **static/root_dir**   
в главный urls.py добавил:  
`url(r'^(?P<file_name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\.(?P<file_type>.*)$', RedirectView.as_view(
        url=settings.STATIC_URL + 'root_dir/%(file_name)s.%(file_type)s/')),`


Нормальное решение?
т.е. получаем универсальный вариант для любых файлов

Comment: и это, в принципе, нормально?, когда используется редирект на другой адрес. яндекс\гугл к этому нормально отнесутся, уведив редиректы на robot.txt ?

Comment: Нормальное решение и нормально должны отнестись: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt см. раздел Переадресация. Можно протестировать здесь https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en и здесь https://webmaster.yandex.ru/robots.xml